# Where to use Event Logger Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I create an Event Controller to log all the request to my APIs. I know that using a controller inside other controller is not a good idea, so... Where do I have to implement it?

EventController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Event;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    /** call this method to get instance */
    public static function instance(){
        if (static::$instance === null){
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    /** protected to prevent cloning */
    protected function __clone(){
    }

    /** protected to prevent instantiation from outside of the class */
    protected function __construct(){
    }

    public function create($type, $description){
        Event::create([
            'id_type'       => $type,
            'date_time'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'id_users'      => auth()->user()->id,
            'description'   => $description       
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not a middleware and apply for each route?

Comment: You can make a trait and use it anywhere (in controller, middleware, etc.). Check this gist out that I made for logging: https://gist.github.com/qumberrizvi/f43933521a3d1aec11d4bf10d49675b2

Comment: @ka_lin It's could be an option.

Comment: @QumberRizvi I will look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 way i suggest:

1.make an `event` and fire it in all actions.
2.make a `middleware` and add it in your each routing(or add in routegroup)

Second one is better.because middlewares made exactly for this reason.All requests that sends to server should pass middleware first .
In brief:you should create middleware with `php artisan make:middleware yourMiddlewareName` and after add your controller code in it you should add name of this middleware in kernel.php in middlewares array.
Now its ready for assign it for every routes you want by append `->middleware("yourMiddlewareName")` in end if each one.